# my graphql resolver with aws s3 functions returning h18 error on heroku?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

my code is like this:

```
try {
      s3.putObject(params);
      await admin.auth().updateUser(contextUser.uid, {
        photoURL: awsPhotoURL,
      });
      if (contextUser.picture) s3.deleteObject(deleteParams);
      return {
        message: 'Success',
        success: true,
        file,
        fileName,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error: ', error);
      return {
        message: error.message,
        success: false,
        file: null,
        fileName: null,
      };
    }
```

basically i don't get an error on localhost, upload operation working as expected but i am getting h18 error once it's already on production. I tried to put await on s3 operations like this:

```
await s3.putObject(params);
```

but i would get warning such as:

> 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.

what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

To use promises/await with the `aws-sdk` you will need to use the promisified version as such:

```
s3.putObject(params).promise()
```

Then `await` should work as expected.

Check out docs on promises [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html) (actually has a S3.putObject() example)

I am not sure this will solve your actual problem but it's a start.